# How do I combine two data frames with different row lengths?

Tags: r, merge

I have two data sets:

### str(a)

```
'data.frame':   525930 obs. of  3 variables:

 $ reg_code  : int  11542359 10077860 10050401 10988998 11465162 10933454 11170863 11291673 12086780 10248250 ...
 $ begin_date: Date, format: "2008-10-01" "1994-06-01" ...
 $ pair_id   : chr  "115423591" "100778601" "100504011" "109889981" ...
```

### str(b)

```
'data.frame':   618655 obs. of  3 variables:

$ reg_code: int  10077860 10050401 10988998 11465162 10933454 11170863 11291673 10248250 10998100 10837319 ...
$ end_date: Date, format: "2006-03-09" "2000-11-16" ...
$ pair_id : chr  "100778601" "100504011" "109889981" "114651621" ...
```

merge:

```
abc<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by="id")
```

but it is throwing an error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
>   arguments imply
>   differing number of rows:15930, 28655, 1

Comment: If you want to get 3 columns df  try abc=merge(a,b,by="id",all=T)

Comment: I tried still it, but it doesn't work as the row length of these two tables is having big difference

Comment: can you post the result of `str(a)` and `str(b)`

Comment: You could use the `dplyr` library for this, which provides faster joining functions. Specifically, if you wanted an inner join, you could use `inner_join(df1, df2, by="id")`, or if you wanted a full join, you could use `full_join(df1, df2, by="id")`. It is not clear from the question though what kind of join you are trying to implement.

Comment: @Maddy try my answer with different length DF and it works `a=data.frame(5:10000,rep("a",10000-4))
colnames(a)=c("ID","a")
b=data.frame(1:10,rep("b",10))
colnames(b)=c("ID","b")
ab=merge(a,b,by="ID",all=T)`

Comment: @Batanichek it still doesn't work, I will add str(a) str(b) to the question

Comment: @Maddy are you try `abc<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by="pair_id",all=T)`?

Comment: I tried, its not working :(

Comment: @Maddy please try again: `abc = merge(x=df1, y=df2, by="pair_id")`

Answer (score 0):

This might seem silly, but just to confirm, are you trying to merge based on "pair_id"? It looks like you're using "id" for the by argument.

If you're simply trying to add one to the other and they have the same columns, you can use rbind().

Comment: And abc<-merge(x=df1,y=df2,by="pair_id") doesn't work?

Comment: nah, it doesn't work, already tried...error:   number of rows in the result exceeds maximum vector length